# Is it faster to set a reference to a local variable of a nested object in ActionScript or the same?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, bytecode

I have an object that is nested several levels deep which I'm referencing multiple times. Is it faster to create and set a reference to that object or does it matter?

Context
I heard that it is faster to create a local reference. This is years ago and for a Visual Basic project. But this is Flash. And the output is a SWF / bytecode. And the compiler could look at that reference and do what I'm doing so that the object does not have to be looked up each time.

For example:

```
public function doStuff():void {

    Model.instance.view1.button1 = button1;
    Model.instance.view1.button2 = button2;
    Model.instance.view1.button3 = button3;
    Model.instance.view1.button4 = button4;
    Model.instance.view1.button5 = button5;
    Model.instance.view1.button6 = button6;

    // more fake code referencing more something.something.something like things 

    for (var i:int;i<something.something.something.length;i++) {
        var result:Object = Controller.staticMethod(button1);
        var result2:Object = Controller.staticMethod(button1);
    }
}
```

Vs:

```
public function doStuff():void {
    var view1:View = Model.instance.view1;

    view1.button1 = button1;
    view1.button2 = button2;
    view1.button3 = button3;
    view1.button4 = button4;
    view1.button5 = button5;
    view1.button6 = button6;
}
```

.
Taking Baris suggestion I tested it for myself. Below are the results (though I don't know how to interpret them into the actual difference ie 'method 1 is .000001 faster than method 2').

**Results**

Test 1

```
            var instance:Model = Model.instance;

            var startTime:int = getTimer();
            for(var i:int = 0; i<10000000; i++){
                instance.url = "";
            }
            trace(getTimer()-startTime); // 826, 929, 823

            var startTime:int = getTimer();
            for(var i:int = 0; i<10000000; i++){
                Model.instance.url = "";
            }
            trace(getTimer()-startTime); // 3483, 3976, 3539
```

Test 2

```
            var instance:Model = Model.instance;

            var localLogo:BitmapImage = Model.instance.logo;

            var startTime:int = getTimer();
            for(var i:int = 0; i<10000000; i++){
                localLogo = logo;
            }
            trace(getTimer()-startTime); // 2070, 2083, 2110

            var startTime:int = getTimer();
            for(var i:int = 0; i<10000000; i++){
                instance.logo = logo;
            }
            trace(getTimer()-startTime); // 2028, 2509, 2154
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, the as3 compiler is not that smart as we think. I think it does that to reduce compilation times.

This page http://upshots.org/actionscript/20-tips-to-optimize-your-actionscript gives us a rule:

> 5: The one-dot rule  When accessing nested variables, anytime a
>   variable requires even one level of scope shift to discover, and is
>   referenced more than once, save it to local variable. In drawing
>   classes, you’ll often see Math.PI / 2 referenced within loops that
>   might iterated hundreds of times each frame – that value should be
>   stored in a local variable. Note that this is not true when
>   referencing member methods. Saving Math.PI to a variable is
>   appropriate; saving Math.round to a variable is not.

It does make difference, but to a software building perspective, the more readable code would be the propper way to do it, unless it's critical code, like a physics section of your app.

Other than making time benchmarks, you can inspect the bytecode too, using this tool http://www.swfwire.com/

Answer (score 2):

I prefer :

```
public function doStuff():void {
    var view1:View = Model.instance.view1;

    view1.button1 = button1;
    view1.button2 = button2;
    view1.button3 = button3;
    view1.button4 = button4;
    view1.button5 = button5;
    view1.button6 = button6;
}
```

I think it looks cleaner, you can profile and see which one is faster but it won't matter performance wise if you are not doing this tons of times in some inner loop.

```
public function doStuff():void {
    var startTime:int = getTimer();
    for(var i:int = 0; i<1000000; i++){
        Model.instance.view1.button1 = button1;
        Model.instance.view1.button2 = button2;
        Model.instance.view1.button3 = button3;
        Model.instance.view1.button4 = button4;
        Model.instance.view1.button5 = button5;
        Model.instance.view1.button6 = button6;
    }
    trace(getTimer()-startTime);
}

public function doStuff():void {
    var startTime:int = getTimer();
    for(var i:int = 0; i<1000000; i++){
        var view1:View = Model.instance.view1;

        view1.button1 = button1;
        view1.button2 = button2;
        view1.button3 = button3;
        view1.button4 = button4;
        view1.button5 = button5;
        view1.button6 = button6;
    }
    trace(getTimer()-startTime);
}
```

Comment: I ran these 10,000,000 times with just Model.instance.button1 = button1 vs var localInstance.button1 = button1 and the difference was 
6206ms for Model.instance call and 2947ms for localInstance.button1 = button1. The thing is is the difference because instance is a getter or is it the lookup. Going to try another test...

Comment: You will probably never do something like this 10m times, so I wouldn't worry too much about which one is faster, just pick the one that is more readable to you(or your team) and stick with it.

Comment: I just updated the question with test results. So using the million times loop how do you figure out what the difference is? I mean given the results you would say something like, "it is .00001 second faster"?

Comment: yeah. it seems too miniscule to matter.

Answer (score 2):

The time to access is probably irrelevant, because you seem to be doing some UI work, and fractions of milliseconds it will take are of no concern. There are other concerns though:

1. You are writing repetitious code - this is bad, always. If it *must* be repeated, you should write a program that repeats it from a single source everywhere, if it may not be repeated - opt not to repeat. The concern is simple. Once you discover that the buttons are in `ModelB.instance.view1` you will need to copy and paste the same code multiple times - of course while doing repetitive work you will make a mistake.
2. AS3 code not only allows, it also welcomes side effects, which, in this case may create undesirable effect. For example, `Model.instance.view1` may be a getter that returns a new copy of view every time it is accessed, or, when accessed, it may alter something else in the internal state of the instance, whatever that is, and performing this change multiple times is undesirable.
3. There's Demeter's rule. When simplified beyond possible, it says that you shouldn't use more than a single dot operator in succession. I.e. an object may only be aware of the property of its own property (or local variable), but never access the property of the property of the property and never further down the line. This imposes unnecessary restriction on the structure of your program. However, sometimes it looks like it might be difficult to avoid, you should strive for a better, self-contained code. More on Demeter's rule here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter

It is not a function of compiler to "optimize" such code, especially because of the side effects. Compiler will faithfully follow the bad code written by a programmer and generate a lot of repetitious assembly because it trusts the programmer that this code is actually needed. Note, I'm not talking about Adobe compiler, which is not an optimizing compiler, and wouldn't remove this code even if the static analysis suggested that. I'm talking about some abstract "ideal" compiler for the language, that would optimally compile the code in question.